# Power Point 2007 won't automatically advance to linked presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, hyperlink, presentations

I'm using PPt 2007.  I've successfully linked 3 PPt presentations; however, I can't advance from the last slide in, for example, presentation #1 unless I click.  I would like PPt to simply advance from the last slide on the 1st presentation to the 1st slide on the 2nd presentation and continue on.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's the nature of links ... you have to click them to activate them.

Is there some reason you can't combine both presentations into one?